# rm -rf always exiting with 0, even if dir does not exist

Tags: macos, rm

I have this command:

```
rm -rf ~/.quicklock; echo $?
rm -rf ~/.quicklock; echo $?
rm -rf ~/.quicklock; echo $?
rm -rf ~/.quicklock; echo $?
```

always exits with 0, even if directory does not exist. I am on a Mac. I thought it would exit with 1 if the directory does not exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`rm -f` does not consider it to be an error if the file does not exist (nor if the directory does not exist, in the case of `rm -rf`).

`man rm` says about `-f` or `--force`:

> ignore nonexistent files and arguments